# Aurelia Validation Matches

Tags: aurelia

I am trying to work out how I would do a startsWith? This is a custom element, it needs to validate that the string starts with a "\"

```
<template>
    <input disabled.bind="readonly" type="text" class="form-control" value.bind="value">
</template>

import {customElement, bindable, inject, bindingMode} from 'aurelia-framework';
import {activationStrategy} from 'aurelia-router';
import $ from 'jquery';
import {Validation} from 'aurelia-validation';



@customElement('url')
@bindable({name: 'value', attribute: 'value', defaultValue: '', defaultBindingMode: bindingMode.twoWay})
@bindable({name: 'readonly', attribute: 'disabled', defaultValue: false, defaultBindingMode: bindingMode.oneWay})
@inject(Element, Validation)
export class Url {
    constructor(element, validation) {
        this.element = element;

        this.validation = validation.on(this)
                    .ensure(this.element)
                    .isNotEmpty()
                    .containsNoSpaces()
                    .matches('/^[\].*/');
    }

    bind(){
        $('.input', this.element).val(this.value);

        if(this.readonly){
            $('.input', this.element).attr('readonly', 'readonly');
        }
    }
}
```

I've looked at http://aurelia.io/validation/#/logical-operators and I think Im doing it right but it throws an error: inner error: TypeError: path.split is not a function

Comment: you don't need to import the element or jquery. Did you plugin the `aurelia-validation` correctly? you should read the aurelia-validation starter guide https://github.com/aurelia/validation/blob/master/doc/Intro.md#installation

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. The function `ensure()` accepts the name of validated field, not the element
2. No need to surround your regex with quotes

It should be something like

```
this.validation = validation.on(this)
                         .ensure('value')   
                         .isNotEmpty()
                         .containsNoSpaces()
                         .matches(/^\\.*$/);
```